# Saving new songs to iPod Library on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ipod

I would like to save audio tracks, generated in my MonoTouch application, to the iPod library, so that they appear in the iPod App, and are synced back up to iTunes.
Can anybody point me in the right direction for achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to save songs into the iTunes storage space on iOS.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is not a limitation of MonoTouch. iOS does not allow this.